# Python - pip module install 2.6 instead of 2.7

Tags: python, django, pip

I use Django 1.3 with Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 10.04.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.1 ...
>>>
```

I'm trying to install the python module [django-grappelli](http://sehmaschine.github.com/django-grappelli/).

```
$ pip install django-grappelli
```

> Requirement already satisfied: django-grappelli in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages

Apparently it's installing into the Python repo's version (2.6) instead of 2.7.
How can I install it on 2.7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run pip with python 2.7. Note that python2.7 isn't provided or supported for Lucid (10.04)

Comment: Finally I uninstalled pip with Synaptic and reinstalled it with easy_install

Comment: how do you run pip with python2.7. And what do you mean that it ain't supported for Lucid? can I still use it?

Comment: I mean Lucid doesn't come with a `python2.7` package. And if you were to install it from a PPA / from source, the python app / module packages in Lucid wouldn't work with it.